# How to modify form fields before validation

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom content type with a lot of fields, and some are required. 
Under some circustances these required fields can be computed from other fields.
I tried to use also hook_node_validate, but i have always the error message because the field is empty when the user sends the form.
It's not easy to implement a javascript solution, since the algorithm to compute the values is not trivial. 
Which kind of solution do you suggest to use?

Comment: Are you trying to alter the field values OR you want ONLY to validate them by calculations?

Comment: I want to alter the field values. In detail, i can compute the value of a field if i fill other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7):

> Note: Changes made to the $node object within your hook implementation will have no effect. The preferred method to change a node's content is to use `hook_node_presave()` instead. If it is really necessary to change the node at the validate stage, you can use `form_set_value()`.

Comment: You are right.
The solution is not to modify form fields before validation. In my case i found a useful workaround: i use hook_form_alter to disable the field, so Drupal doesn't perform the validation on that field. Maybe better is to change the validation function for that field.

Comment: Hi,
I need same workaround but this case is with **user points** form, I want to use **presave** before user points module hit validate by my **custom module** and add custom points so that validation can also work fine.